# Infected Windows File Server, should we clean or wipe?

Tags: windows-server-2003, anti-virus, malware

I'm troubleshooting a friend's Windows 2k3 file server (that I had setup for them a few weeks ago). It got infected by a tenga.gen virus and he's trying to clean it now but doesn't have a server anti-virus on hand.

However, in the long run, would it be recommended to try to clean the server and get all traces of the virus off or just do a wipe and reinstall?

Normally, I would recommend the wipe and reinstall with a new virus scan from the start and slowly migrate verified cleaned files back onto it, but I moved out of the area and can't help in person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once code has been allowed to run with **administrative** privelages, the machine can no longer be trusted.

File listings, registry keys, network access - can all be comprimised; and you wouldn't be able to tell from the machine itself.

You can hope that the virus isn't a bad one, and didn't do the very nasty things. But the only way to be sure is to reinstall.

Comment: +1: You can never really feel good about the machine again, after it's been compromised. Cleaning a file server is a special nightmare as well, because the infection could be anywhere.

Comment: +1: It presents a nice opportunity to test your scripted/imaged OS deployment and backup restoration operations. :)

Comment: " I say we take off, and nuke the site from orbit. It's the onyl way to be sure." - very wise woman

Answer (score 1):

Given [this analysis](http://www.sophos.com/security/analyses/viruses-and-spyware/w32tengaa.html) from Sophos, wipe and reinstall. It enables a remote command and control session, meaning anything else could be on there as well. So it's not just Win32/Tenga that you're worried about, but whatever else has been deployed subsequent to the infection.